# is there a way to hot plug all functions of a pcie device instead of just function 0?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, pci-express

It is often that we have pcie devices for example GPUs. That has multiple functions.
I can statically assign all the functions to a domain by editing the XML.
However, I would like to be about detach/attach the hostdev live.
So far I can only put 1 function into xml for `virsh attach-device` or `attachDeviceFlags(xml, flags)`
But if I try to run the attach-device multiple times to attach other function of a pcie device it spit out:

```
libvirt.libvirtError: internal error: Only PCI device addresses with function=0 are supported
```

Some discuss about this from [8 years ago](https://libvir-list.redhat.narkive.com/4Mql5dMc/libvirt-hot-plug-multi-function-pci-devices).

> There has recently been some work in qemu to "save up" any requests to
> attach devices with function > 0, then present them all to the guest at
> once when function 0 is attached.

But I cannot find any information about it. Is there any solution for this after all these years?